# How to get available search results per given time from google?

Tags: google-search-api

I would love to get how many search results are available per given time (say yesterday, or last week) from Google, i want something more "accurate" than Google trends, for a project i am building, so for example :

```
Potato - Last 24 hours - 100 results.
Potato - Last week - 5000 results
```

and so on ... is this possible?.

Ps: i know this might not even be practical, but i've been asked to add this feature ...